# Getting CSV files to work on Heroku rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, csv, heroku, import

I am trying to import ailments.csv to work on Heroku and its just not wanting to work properly. I have searched and searched with no real solutions.

Locally it is working fine and the ailments show.

Here is the Heroku app link so you can see what I'm having issues with. 
https://sleepy-garden-73993.herokuapp.com/

HOW TO GET TO AILMENTS: 
-Click on "check your address"
-Enter 202 tryon st for address, and 28207 for zip code (This is within our service area)
-There will be a dropdown that says select your ailment. And you can see its blank. It should be displaying the ailments within the csv file.

LINK TO GITHUB REPO: 
https://github.com/kbachand/ginger_ails

Its too much code to post on here so it will be easier for you to see how I've done things on the github repo.

Import rake code

```
require 'csv'
namespace :import_ailment do
desc "Import ailment from a CSV file"
task ailments: :environment do
CSV.foreach("ailments.csv") do |row|
    name, description, shopping_list, price = row
    Ailment.create(name: name, description: description, shopping_list: shopping_list, price: price)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How many ailments are in the database?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Have you run `heroku run rake import_ailment:ailments`?

Comment: @infused that command worked! I was doing it locally without the heroku which was why it didn't work on heroku. Thanks!

Comment: @infused so now the ailments show thanks to that command BUT when I choose "purchase remedy kit" I get the we're sorry but something went wrong page and the log when I inspect the page says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: @infused this is the error in the log from heroku.2016-11-02T17:52:58.659592+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[35mCart Load (1.7ms)[0m  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
2016-11-02T17:52:58.661996+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[36mUser Load (2.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (4) LIMIT 1[0m
2016-11-02T17:52:58.662156+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 5.5ms)
2016-11-02T17:52:58.662810+00:00 app[web.1]:

Comment: There's no error in that section of log.  Try increasing the number of lines shown until you can find the actual error. Maybe 1000 lines? `heroku logs -n 1000` or even `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: @infused 2016-11-02T17:52:58.659592+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[35mCart Load (1.7ms)[0m  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
2016-11-02T17:52:58.661996+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[36mUser Load (2.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (4) LIMIT 1[0m
2016-11-02T17:52:58.662156+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 5.5ms)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer

Comment: @infused the comments don't let me paste it all but thats the error its throwing. Once again it works locally so I'm just confused as to why I'm getting the error.

Comment: Could you have migrations that have not been run on heroku with `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: @infused I tried that as well as heroku run rake db:reset and imported the ailments again with no luck. Same error.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure then.  You might try creating a new question for this new issue.

Comment: @infused I will do. Thanks for the help getting the ailments to show!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you run the migration on Heroku with:

```
heroku run rake import_ailment:ailments
```